# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS booting into BIOS after failed FireFox upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have a desktop machine with an ASUS Z97-K motherboard with an SSD Drive (SDE) that contains Ubuntu as well as the application code/tier for ownCloud. The majority of my data sits on a 4 disk SATA (3TB each) RAID array (disks SDA to SDD). See below.

[image: Hard Drive Listing]

I recently booted the machine and everything was working fine until I tried to update Mozilla. I cancelled the update midway thru the process (by clicking the cancel button) and this seems to somehow have corrupted the files that allow the ubuntu to boot properly to the login screen. Instead, the machine boots straight into the bios.

I am unable to access Grub by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> on the initial boot up and Boot-Repair doesn’t complete as I get the following error:

> GPT detected. Please create a Bios-Boot (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.

[image: Boot-Repair Error]

I have launched GParted but have not been able to address.

[image: GParted Image]

I have also tried booting thru the Live CD and then opting to 'install ubuntu' with the intention of updating/repairing the system files and without deleting the other application files or data.

However, the only option I get is to reinstall and delete whatever is on my SDE drive. One problem is that I cannot remember if I encrypted my ownCloud data (on the RAID) so reinstalling Ubuntu may make the data tier permanently inaccessible.

At this point my thinking is that the best way to fix the problem is to use the Live CD to bootup, mount the SDE drive (internal desktop SSD with Ubuntu on it) and upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu (say version 18). However, I have been unable to find anything that describes the exact steps to doing this. Running `sudo apt-get update`/`upgrade` only affects the Live CD and not the disk (SDE) where the corrupted version of Ubuntu currently resides.

I would very much welcome any help on how tto 'point' the upgrade/fix procedure at the internal desktop partition where Ubuntu resides or any alternatives on how to fix this. Again, I am not technical so the simpler the explanation and specific the steps, the better. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you cancel? Because it took too long? It could be a problem with the SSD all along.

Comment: No, not because it was taking long.  I thought it might be performing a full upgrade of my entire system vs. just upgrading the browser.  Unfortunately, I didn't realize hitting cancel would leave it with mid-stream changes as opposed to reversing the system back to it's original state.